# Error "No component for supporting the service Abp.AspNetCore.MultiTenancy.DomainTenantResolveContributor was found" when run test function

Tags: unit-testing, aspnetboilerplate

I working with Asp.net boilerplate v.5.12.0
The project works fine with Enabling MultiTenancy
And now we need to use the unit test function but when I start to run it I get this error for all functions "No component for supporting the service Abp.AspNetCore.MultiTenancy.DomainTenantResolveContributor was found"
I know I should add a resolver for it but I don't know how Or even if I think right or not
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searches, The solution was I need to add this code into PreInitialize() in ProjectNameTestBaseModule

```
IocManager.Register<IWebMultiTenancyConfiguration, WebMultiTenancyConfiguration>();
IocManager.Register<DomainTenantResolveContributor>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
IocManager.Register<HttpHeaderTenantResolveContributor>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
IocManager.Register<HttpCookieTenantResolveContributor>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```